# Python run multiple commands after assert

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert

How do I run multiple commands after calling an `assert` statement? For example, here's what I would like to do (without using assert):

```
x = False
if x != True:
    my_func()
    raise ValueError("My statement")
```

This does exactly what I want, but it seems more Pythonic to use `assert` in this case. I cannot figure out how to do multiple things after calling `assert`. Here's what I'm trying to do (but with incorrect syntax):

```
x = False
assert x == True, my_func() "My statement"
```

Comment: Why would it be more Pythonic to use assert? On the contrary, using exceptions is the right way.

Comment: It just seemed like a natural place to use assert, but I guess not. I'll use the exception then.

Comment: I would suggest using a try statement here, in which case you can do proper exception handling and execute multiple commands if something goes right or wrong.

Comment: Could you try with `assert x == True, [my_func(),  "My statement"][1]`

Comment: Nice Adbul, that works as well

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
assert x == True, [my_func(), "My statement"][1]
```

**DEMO**

```
def my_func():
    print("my function")

x = False
assert x == True, [my_func(),  "My statement"][1]
```

OUTPUT

```
my function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abdul.niyas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/a.py", line 5, in <module>
    assert x == True, [my_func(),  "My statement"][1]
AssertionError: My statement
```

Comment: Clever solution. But in my opinion still a lot harder to read then the classic `if not x: ...`.